# asp.net membership api integration with php

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, roles

Fairly new to this so go easy ;-)

Just looking for some general advice really. I'm currently creating a front end system to integrate with a back end system that someone else has created. My front end system just consists of a website, a sign up form where customers can register. This is integrated with our payment partners and is done through PHP (this is the language I know best). Up until now, I have not seen the back end, so I have been using a mysql database to test my scripts etc.

So now I'm at the point where I need to update the database at the back end in order to set up the user accounts. Silly me for thinking this would just be as simple as using an insert statement. The backend is done in asp.net c# and uses sql server. In order to create new users, the guy who wrote the backend uses the asp.net membership api. This creates the user but also creates a LOT of tables in the database.

Does anyone know how I should go about integrating these two? Is there anything I can use PHP-wise that will work with the asp.net membership api?

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: do you want to make user tables for back end and front end in single database?

Comment: Ideally, what I'd like to do is use the data that I've collected in the form to populate the back end database. So yes, I wouldn't mind having it as a single database.

Comment: I don't know PHP but could it be as simple as just using PHP's curl functions to post your form data to the asp.net membership page??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both the php and the asp.net code are displaying information from the same database at the back end this should not be a problem.

asp membership is designed to be simple to use, to be sure you pull the right information use the generated stored procedures that the .net framework would have generated for you in your php code ... this will result in the raw data that the asp.net security objects uses being returned in the same format.

how you then use that data is entirely up to you.

You could ask the guy that created the asp.net components to create a simply web service for you ? ... that would result in an interface in to his asp.net components in a standards driven soap format ... but i think the stored procedures in the database should give you all the information you need.

Hopefully you're ok with making stored procedure calls on a sql db ... as i understand it it's not all that different to mysql calls on php :)